# Head Pose estimation using Car Interiors depth infromation

Tags: computer-vision, reference-request, pose-estimation

I am trying to determine head pose of a driver sitting in a car with the depth interiors of the car known to me. Is there any research work which exploits that information in determining the head pose of the driver ?
One paper along the lines of using depth as a privileged information are,

1. https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.07376
   which talks about using depth as a privileged information while training and not while inferring.

Also there are papers where depth is used as an auxiliary depth information in facial recognition.
https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_cvpr_2018/html/Liu_Learning_Deep_Models_CVPR_2018_paper.html

But I am not able to find any reference where the depth of the background is used as an additional information in head pose/hand pose/human pose estimation.
Any help would be great!

Comment: What are your findings so far? Tell us what you have found so far.

Comment: Something along the lines of depth privileged information, https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.07376 for hand. I am finding quite a few papers where the depth map is available for the object in interest but not the background.

Comment: Sadly, I am not finding anything which has contextual depth information for doing head pose/hand pose/human pose estimation.

Comment: Edit your post to include this information there.

Comment: @nbro : Have edited the post.